# How do I interpret this answer?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the following predicate exersice:

> Explain why the two following sentences have different meanings (by a description of a
>   situation in which the sentences have a different truth-value)
>
> - There is exactly one boy who loves exactly one girl. $(\exists!x \exists!y (Bx\land Gy\land Lxy))$
> - There is exactly one girl who is loved by exactly one boy. $(\exists!y \exists!x (Bx \land Gy \land
>   Lxy))$

The answer is given as follows:

[image: answer]

I see here two guys and girls (being black or white dots) and a guy having a love relation to a girl, and a guy having a love relation to two different girls.

I don't see how this fits either formula. Or even how the switching of $\exists!x \exists!y$ to $\exists!y \exists!x$ has *any* impact on the meaning of the predicate.

Comment: could it be that this image is representing the different singular x and y these formulas pertain to. As the first would show the relation between the black dot to the white dot on the left side and the second formula is the relation of the white dot accepting the black dots love relation.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA certainly not... you may not swap the x's and y's...

Comment: The key-point is that the "uniqueness quantifier" is applied to a "complex" predicate. If we have $\exists ! x Bx$ this means that there is a single Boy. If we have $\exists x (Bx \land Px)$, this does not imply that we have a single boy, but we must have only one Boy that is P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following four scenarios:

> You have many boys and two girls.  One of the boys loves only the first girl and does not love the second girl.  All other boys love both girls.

Here there is a unique boy who loves a single girl.  There is not a unique girl who is loved only once.

> You have many boys and two girls.  One of the boys loves both girls.  All other boys love only the second girl.

Here there is not a unique boy who loves only one girl.  There is a unique girl who is loved only once.

> You have many boys and two girls.  One of the boys loves only the first girl. All other boys love only the second girl.

Here there is both a unique boy who loves a single girl and a single girl who is loved only once.

> You have many boys and two girls.  All of the boys love all of the girls.

Here there are no boys who love only one girl and there are no girls who are loved only once.

---

As for the image provided as the "answer", it certainly isn't a clear answer but I interpret it as trying to get across the idea that a unique boy loving one girl is a result of the far left black dot and it's interaction with the first white dot.  A unique girl being loved by a unique boy is a result of the far right white dot being loved by the right black dot.  Had these expressions been the same, then surely it would have been a result of the same dots, not different ones.

In the image, both expressions have the same truth value.  If their goal was to show a situation where the expressions have different truth values, then they failed and their "answer" is incorrect.